# Update Version field if update row with one sequence per table

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I have table with "Version" field which have to have unique value per table (may be sequence). Version value must update when row updates.

I'm using Fluent NHibernate and SQLite.

Please note that the Version field is integer type. When I used datetime type for version all was OK because it was unique per table.
When using int type it is unique per row.

```
this.Version(x => x.Version).Column("Version");
```

Comment: Why should the version of an entity (row) be unique for all entities? If two new entities are created, both have a version of 1. If an entity is modified, its version is incremented by 1. That's just how the version works in NHibernate. For what do you need that column?

Comment: By queries like "select * from Entities where Version > 5" retrieve all entities which was updated, inserted after version 5.

Comment: Actually my Version column is like some sort of Revision

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the version column as a "version" like NHibernate defines it, you should just map it as a property and use a different column for NHibernate versioning.

You could create a trigger to fill your column with the sequence value on insert and map it as follows:

```
Map(x => x.Version).Column("Version")
   .Generated.Insert()
   .Not.Insert()
   .Not.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if your `Version` becomes a `LastModified` `DateTime` your `Revision` approach will be more clear, also it becomes obvious that version can not really be that unique across whole table.

Getting a `DateTime.UtcDate` or calling same function in db can be easier than handing an autoincrement unique function in db, if you don't have access to sequences.

If that will suit your needs I think its simpler to program than trigger version which I also like. That said I don't think we can map such behavior using FluentNHibernate either..

Comment: I think that using DateTime for revision is not appropriate because we can't be sure about chronological sequence of DateTime values (we have time sync, etc)

Comment: ah I see, then it cannot indeed fit your needs.